# Why is my desktop LAN slower than my laptop?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I've just upgraded from Virgin 30Mb to Virgin 100Mb.  When speed testing my laptop (5yr old, win Vista) I get around 90Mb but when testing my desktop (3yr old, win 7 64bit) I get 60Mb. These results are using the same wired connection, literally unplugging one and plugging in the other.  I've replaced the Ethernet card and it hasn't made any difference, turned off the firewall & anti-virus, updated the bios on the mobo, updated all the Ethernet drivers, still no-joy.  It's worth saying that the differential between the two machines is always constant, if I get 80 on the laptop it will be 50 on the desktop.  Its always 30Mbps behind, something is pulling it down and I don't know what.  The upload speed is also slower, 16Mbps on the laptop, 10Mbps on the desktop.  I'm close to launching the pc out of the window!  Please help.

Comment: Hardware specs please.  For example a slow hard drive could significantly hurt performance.

Comment: Win 7 64bit,  ASUS P7P55d Deluxe LGA1156,  Intel Core i5 670 3.47Ghz,  6GB DDR2,  ATi Radeon 5800,  Western Digital WDC WD750 Black (400Gb free).

Comment: Have you updated the other drivers like your storage driver? Try slimdrivers (google it)

Comment: Just updated all drivers, plenty were out of date, but unfortunately none of them have have rectified the fault.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using for the test?  Same on both machines?  If IE on the desktop, try using IE (No Add-Ons) from Start > Accessories > System Tools.  Let us know ...

Comment: IE 9 on the laptop, IE 10 on the desktop.  I have tried chrome on both too and that came out with the same result.  Also compared the 32 & 64bit versions of IE 10 but there was no difference.  As you suggested, I've tried it with no add-ons but it was still 30Mbps down.